# How do I view what Safari is downloading?

Tags: safari

When idle, Safari seems to download something that consumes significant bandwidth (about 800 KB/s). The auto-install setting under *Extensions > Updates* is disabled/unchecked, so I don't think it's one of my extensions (AdBlock and Tab Duplicator). How do I view what it's trying to download or the server it's accessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a general way to check network usage (transferred bytes, opened urls and files, etc.) of every process.

Open the Activity Monitor -> Network (tab). There you should see all safari web pages as a separate process name, which usually start with `http://website address...` (They usually have the bundle icon, a white box). There are columns for `Sent Bytes` and `Rcvd Bytes` which indicates how many bytes that page (or process) is sent or received.

[image]

To see the url addresses which that process is connected to, you can select that process and click on the `(i)` button at the top of the window (or by pressing `CMD+i` on the keyboard). A window will open with the title of `Safari Web Content`, click on the `Open Files and Ports` tab, scroll to the down most part of the text box, there you can see the connection urls. The local file addresses for caching or downloading files are also available in the text box.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me narrow down the problem. I noticed the traffic coming from my GMail tab, which seemed odd. It turned out to be GMail's Chat feature, which I've now disabled. No more bandwidth suck.

Comment: You're welcome :-) I'm glad it helped you finding the issue. As you have noticed, the chat feature keep its connection to the server open, because it has to check your contacts status and transfer other related data.

Comment: I don't see a reason chat needs to download *that much* data when the service is not even being used. It's a constant download stream at 800 Mbps.

Comment: Wow! that's really weird!! certainly something was wrong with it...